# How to get render to texture working?

Tags: python, rendering, texturing, game-engine, camera

I have read the manual, watched tutorials, and read forum posts. So far they have all been based on GLSL and using Python. Including multi-texture in my search results in tuts about applying multiple textures, making them one, etc.. However, so far I have not been able to get "Render-to-Texture" to work in 2.78c using multi-texture and appending, copy/pasting, and (in some cases) handwriting code from the video screen and typing it into the text editor directly.

As an RTS the texture (a map) will set inside a frame from an Overlay Scene.

As the .blend is now: Everything is shadeless. I believe that I unwrapped the texture correctly as it was a square picture applied to a square plane and I didn't have to adjust it like in the tutorials (it 'just fit' and it appears in the editor, render, and game play mode). My "Always" Sensor is set to "Pulse-True". The camera is Orthographic at Scale: 80.

Also I did try appending the texture from a previous save to the Game Scene and Childed (?) it to the camera while restricting the visibility, select-ability, and rendering of it in the overlay scene and, also, deleting it altogether. And I have used specular/ shaded materials with lamps (there is an inactive hemi-spherical currently in the .blend).

Wishing to keep the game playable for myself (two years ago I paid $300 for my laptop), I have sought ways that enable this (9 Ways To Optimize...). Plus I'm a noob so coming up with my own scripts and UPBGE or Blender Sensei are not a current option.

A tutorial (or three) or correct search terms should suffice. Perhaps my lexicon did not match the title or is not generating accurate results.

Thank you to you and to those that have already helped make this game. Especially the free to own, play, and modify aspects.

Edit: When I ask fo tutorials I meant those that already exist.

Comment: Can you put an image of what you want to achieve? I do not understand your question